# Reaching out to another manager about moving to another Business Unit

Tags: communication, employer-relations, entry-level

I've been recently employed in a large company in the IT field. It's my entry job, fresh out of a masters degree, and I am in the first month of my probation period.

The Business Unit I'm in specializes in a particular field (topic X) that I'm not particularly fond of, nor I have a strong academic background on it. However, I joined that team under the (verbal) promise from another manager that I will be moved to Business Unit Y in one or two months.

Assuming that the manager will be true to his world (could be a big assumption, I know) how do I reach out to him to let him know I'm currently working my probation period at the company?

Said manager has stressed out as this should be made **unofficially**, as being hired in a BU and moving immediately to another could seem disrespectful towards manager X.

I've got the feeling that he doesn't want to discuss this over the company mail system. As shady as it seems, my options right now are hoping to meet him at work or calling him over the phone.

**Update**: I've checked with HR, and there is no internal policy or limit for BU transfer. Apparantely it's something to be discussed between managers.

Comment: What is the **company's** policy on switching business units?  Most places I have worked is at least 6 months or even a year.  Find out what the policy is **first**.

Comment: I've been told it's not a big deal, but I'm struggling to find written data about it. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Not really clear on what you asking?

Comment: @Liquid Ask your HR rep.  I would as in a "Just in case down the road I want to" type of way.

Comment: "I've been told it's not a big deal, but I'm struggling to find written data about it"  - Didn`t you get a by-Laws binder to read on your first week?

Comment: @Strader I'm asking if it's more professional to call him over the phone or approach him during work hours, or whatever else. Also, I did get a bunch of documents, but they were about privacy and security measures.

Comment: Why would they bring into BU X if the intent was to move you to BU Y in two months. Pretty sure BU X was not told about that plan.

Comment: IMHO, I wouldn`t rock the boat while in probation period.

Comment: Unless you only want to work there if in BU X

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask HR what the policy is regarding department / BU transfers **first**.

If there isn't a policy, well then you can start the conversations and figure out the best way to handle this.  ( Preferably between the two managers )  Be open and honest with both managers regarding your desire to transfer and *why*.

Be prepared that there may in fact be a policy stating that you have to serve in a given position for a certain amount of time.  ( in the USA 6 months to a year is normal )